# How do I compare captcha variable

Tags: javascript, php

How to compare these variable in javascript? with if statement.

```
echo $code1 = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];
echo $code2 = $_POST["code_input"]
```

Comment: If you need to do anything in JavaScript based on those server-side values - then you can do the comparison on the server-side already, and based upon that output the code that triggers the JS action, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if I understand your question correctly. 
But from your description I would say, you can compare it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let code1 = "<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['code']; ?>";
let code2 = "<?php echo $_POST['code_input']; ?>";
if(code1 === code2) {
   //...do something
} 
</script>
```